# Oracle SQL Trigger insert/update---

Tags: triggers, oracle11g, procedure, ora-04091

Please help me with the issue, I want to write a trigger where I can insert the values into new table whenever insert/update happens in source table.

Below is the table structure from where I want to fetch data into another table.

**LISTING TABLE**

`Name                     Null     Type`

---

`LISTINGID                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(28)`
`LISTINGMANAGERID         NOT NULL VARCHAR2(28)`
`MANAGEAVAILABILITYFLAG            VARCHAR2(1)`
`AVAILABILITYTEXT                  VARCHAR2(2000)`

`AREAINQUIRYFLAG                   VARCHAR2(1)`
`COUNTRYTEXT                       VARCHAR2(50)`
`STATEPROVINCETEXT                 VARCHAR2(50)`
`CITYTEXT                          VARCHAR2(50)`
`CHECKINTIME                       VARCHAR2(10)`
`CHECKOUTTIME                      VARCHAR2(10)`
`TIMEZONEID                        VARCHAR2(20)`

`PERSONALLINKURL                   VARCHAR2(150)`

`GOLDSUBSCRIPTIONSINCE             DATE`
`AUDITPASSFLAG            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)`
`MGRONLINEFLAG            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)`
`ADMINAPPROVALFLAG        NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)`
`DELETEDFLAG                       VARCHAR2(1)`
`LASTUPDATED              NOT NULL DATE`
`UPDATEDBY                NOT NULL VARCHAR2(28)`
`OCA                      NOT NULL NUMBER(38)`
`SUSPENDEDFLAG            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)`
`POSSIBLEFEATUREDCITYFLAG NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1)`
`TOTALPHOTOS                       NUMBER(38)`
`SUSPENDEDDATE                     DATE`
`OFFLINEDATE                       DATE`
`CURRENCY                          VARCHAR2(3)`
`POINTCHARGE                       VARCHAR2(2)`
`AVERAGEOFREVIEWS                  FLOAT(126)`
`NUMBEROFREVIEWS                   NUMBER(38)`
`RENTALMODEL                       VARCHAR2(10)`
`NOTHANKS                          VARCHAR2(1)`
`DIGITALSIGN                       VARCHAR2(50)`

**Need result in below table with any update or new insert from listing table.**

i)listingid should contain listingid's from listing table.

ii)OFFLINE COLUMN should contain data with below condition.

AuditPassFlag = 'Y' AND AdminApprovalFlag='Y' AND MgrOnlineFlag='Y'  AND DeletedFlag is NULL  AND SuspendedFlag !='Y'

iii)TIMESTAMP COLUMN lastupdated date from listing table.

**LISTING_LASTUPDATE TABLE**

Name       Null     Type

---

`LISTINGID  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)`

`IS_OFFLINE          VARCHAR2(1)`

`TIMESTAMP           TIMESTAMP(0)`

Below the trigger I am have written:

Its not working properly for where condition which means Listing is online: apart from that its work fine.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER listingLast_updated
   AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE
   ON listing
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   L_Listingid             VARCHAR2 (20);

   L_ISOFFLINE             VARCHAR2 (1);

   LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP   DATE;
BEGIN
   SELECT SYSDATE INTO LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP FROM DUAL;

   IF (    :NEW.AuditPassFlag = 'Y'
       AND :NEW.AdminApprovalFlag = 'Y'
       AND :NEW.MgrOnlineFlag = 'Y'
       AND :NEW.DeletedFlag IS NULL
       AND :NEW.SuspendedFlag != 'Y') THEN
      L_ISOFFLINE := 'Y';
   ELSE
      L_ISOFFLINE := 'N';

      INSERT
        INTO LISTING_LastUPDATED (LISTINGID, IS_OFFLINE, LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP)
      VALUES (:NEW.LISTINGID, L_ISOFFLINE, LASTUPDATED_TIMESTAMP);
   END IF;
END;
```

Comment: This is not a code-writing service.  Is there some specific aspect of creating a trigger that you need help with?  I'm sure Oracle spends a lot of money writing their documentation, and its pretty good.  Maybe try reading it - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/triggers.htm

Comment: @OldProgrammer: I have shared the written tirgger, please have look at it.

Comment: What do you mean, is not working - runtime error, or compile error?  There is no "WHERE" in your trigger code.  Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You've written:

> Need result in below table with any update or new insert from listing table.

That is not what your trigger does. Take another look at your IF statement. It simplifies to:

```
if ... then
   ...
else
   insert ...
end if;
```

Your INSERT is in the ELSE clause. You will therefore execute the INSERT when the initial IF statement is true. Not *"with **any** update or new insert"*.

There are a number of other things you can change:

1. The variable `L_Listingid` is never used, remove it.
2. There's no need to use SELECT INTO ... in order to assign a variable. This can be done as follows in the declaration block:

   ```
   lastupdated_timestamp date := sysdate;
   ```

   However, I see no particular need for this variable to exist, so you can remove it and simply use SYSDATE in your sole INSERT.
3. There's no need to execute an ELSE at all. Set the default value of `L_ISOFFLINE` to be N and then use that if the IF condition doesn't evaluate to be true.
4. Two cosmetic changes, there's no need to wrap the ANDs in brackets; I've added the trigger name to the END so it's clearer.

You've you've also written:

> TIMESTAMP COLUMN lastupdated date from listing table.

You actually have a LASTUPDATED date in your LISTING  table, which means you're not following your own guidelines. You should use the column instead.

Putting all this together, your trigger might look like this:

```
create or replace trigger listinglast_updated
   after insert or update
   on listing
   for each row
declare

   l_isoffline varchar2(1) := 'N';

begin

   if :new.auditpassflag = 'Y'
       and :new.adminapprovalflag = 'Y'
       and :new.mgronlineflag = 'Y'
       and :new.deletedflag is null
       and :new.suspendedflag != 'Y' then

      l_isoffline := 'Y';

   end if;

   insert into listing_lastupdated (listingid, is_offline, lastupdated_timestamp)
   values (:new.listingid, l_isoffline, :new.lastupdated);

end listinglast_updated;
```

Comment: Thanks Ben for your comments...I have re-written and removed the unnecessary thing from the trigger. I did not use LastUpdated from Listing table becoz I wanted to have time also along with date and I cannot make changes in Base table.

Comment: So you just replaced `:new.lastupdated` with `sysdate` then @Aryan?